# Smooth Scroll conflicts with Fancybox "Append Custom Content"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fancybox

I am using "Smooth scroll" from CSS tricks to navigate on my one page (bootstrap 3)website.
And I am also using Fancy box to display my portfolio items.

Now that all works FINE, untill I try to append the data displayed in the fancybox with the data from a div (Which holds the portfolio-item content)

I think this conflicts because both the Jquery's (Smoothscroll and Fancybox) use anchor tags.

Here is the smoothscroll script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the fancybox script thats loads the fancybox and triggers it with the class, and also the script that gets the content from a seperate div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>


<!--FANCYBOX DISPLAY CONTENT FROM DIV -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterLoad   : function() {
            this.inner.prepend( '<h1>1. My custom title</h1>' );
            this.content = '<h1>2. My custom title</h1>' + this.content.html();
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I comment out the smoothscroll script, the fancybox works fine. So it has to be the smoothscroll.

Any idea on how this could be fixed?

You can see the website here with the fancybox working, so the smoothscroll is disabled:
http://www.baasdesign.nl/responsive/

Comment: your code above doesn't correspond to the one on the website of reference. You have syntax js errors (API options are just right after `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`)

Answer (score 0):

The class, for example 'fancy-content' where you hide the fancy content before you load with the fancybox link, don't make it "display: none", do as in the example below:

```
/* element bifore load */ .fancy-content{ display: block; /*not none*/ height: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; } /*  element after load in fancybox inner */ .fancybox-inner .fancy-content{ height: auto; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible;}
```

One of the reason is that, the scroll, doesn't know the width and height, of the content with scroll, because the element is display none. :-) I hope this help!